# Requirejs data-main is not setting the baseUrl

Tags: requirejs

I set the data-main for Requirejs and according to the documentation that should set the baseUrl for all my script files.  But this is not the case.
My folder structure is this:

```
Home/Index.html
Content/scripts/main.js
Content/scripts/libs/require/require.js
Content/scripts/libs/jquery/require_jquery.js
Content/scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.mins.js
```

Here is the script tag in my **Index.html**:

```
<script data-main="/PAWS/Content/scripts/main.js" src="/PAWS/Content/scripts/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would assume it would set my baseUrl to /PAWS/Content/scripts/ but its not working for me. In my **main.js** I do this:

```
require(
    { paths: 
        {   jquery: 'libs/jquery',
            knockout: 'libs/knockout'
        }
    },

    ['jquery/require_jquery'],


    function ($) { .... }
);
```

In my **require_jquery.js** file I do this:

```
define(["libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"], function () {
    return jQuery;
});
```

But I get a 404 error saying that:

```
GET http://localhost/PAWS/Home/libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js 404 NOT FOUND
```

You see.. my baseUrl should be /PAWS/Content/scripts... But it totally ignores my data-main attribute setting and just resolves /PAWS/Home/ to be the baseUrl.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [RequireJS API docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles):

> However, if the dependency name has one of the following properties, it is treated as a regular file 
>   path, like something that was passed to a `<script src="">` tag:
>
> - Ends in ".js".
> - Starts with a "/".
> - Contains an URL protocol, like "http:" or "https:".

From this, it appears that your explicit ".js" on the end of `libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is confounding your path re: baseUrl.  Try `libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min` instead.